# ReflectionHelper*java.lang.NoSuchFieldException

Tags: android, webservice-client

I am trying to call webservice from my android app. I am getting below error in my logcat. My webservice is working fine, because I am able to call the methods from java client.

```
Error in logcat:

06-13 13:19:47.585: I/System.out(1317): validateUserAndReturnDashBoard
06-13 13:19:48.143: D/dalvikvm(1317): GC_CONCURRENT freed 256K, 9% free 4147K/4520K, paused 85ms+106ms, total 327ms
06-13 13:19:48.143: D/dalvikvm(1317): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 22ms
06-13 13:19:48.333: I/System.out(1317): Retrieving document at ''.
06-13 13:19:49.243: D/dalvikvm(1317): GC_CONCURRENT freed 400K, 11% free 4250K/4768K, paused 100ms+104ms, total 308ms
06-13 13:19:49.263: I/System.out(1317): Retrieving schema at '../gw/xsd/guidewire/soapheaders.xsd', relative to 'xxxx://xxx.xxx.x.x:8080/cc/ws/com/LoginAppAPI?WSDL'.
06-13 13:19:49.703: I/System.out(1317): Full Request XML Is <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ws="null" ><soap:Header/><soap:Body><ws:validateUserAndReturnDashBoard></ws:validateUserAndReturnDashBoard></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
06-13 13:19:49.703: I/System.out(1317): Response Class: com.example.com.loginappapi.ValidateUserAndReturnDashBoardResponse
06-13 13:19:50.134: I/System.out(1317): Status  200
06-13 13:19:50.134: I/System.out(1317): WSInvocationHandler: Status  200
06-13 13:19:50.154: I/System.out(1317): WSInvocationHandler: Response: <?xml version="1.0"?>
06-13 13:19:50.154: I/System.out(1317): <soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
06-13 13:19:50.154: I/System.out(1317):   <soap12:Body>
06-13 13:19:50.154: I/System.out(1317):     <soap12:Fault>
06-13 13:19:50.154: I/System.out(1317):       <soap12:Code>
06-13 13:19:50.154: I/System.out(1317):         <soap12:Value>soap12:Sender</soap12:Value>
06-13 13:19:50.154: I/System.out(1317):       </soap12:Code>
06-13 13:19:50.154: I/System.out(1317):       <soap12:Reason>
06-13 13:19:50.163: I/System.out(1317):         <soap12:Text xml:lang="">No such operation {null}validateUserAndReturnDashBoard in service com.LoginAppAPI</soap12:Text>
06-13 13:19:50.163: I/System.out(1317):       </soap12:Reason>
06-13 13:19:50.186: I/System.out(1317):     </soap12:Fault>
06-13 13:19:50.186: I/System.out(1317):   </soap12:Body>
06-13 13:19:50.186: I/System.out(1317): </soap12:Envelope>
06-13 13:19:50.186: I/System.out(1317): ReflectionHelper*java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: return
06-13 13:19:50.193: I/System.out(1317): FieldnameFound for return
06-13 13:19:50.193: I/System.out(1317): ReflectionHelper*java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: return
06-13 13:19:50.206: I/System.out(1317): ReflectionHelper*java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: code
06-13 13:19:50.213: W/System.err(1317): org.jinouts.ws.exception.FieldNotMatchedException
06-13 13:19:50.226: W/System.err(1317):     at hu.javaforum.commons.ReflectionHelper.getFieldClass(ReflectionHelper.java:504)
06-13 13:19:50.246: W/System.err(1317):     at hu.javaforum.android.androidsoap.GenericHandler.startElement(GenericHandler.java:345)
06-13 13:19:50.246: W/System.err(1317):     at hu.javaforum.android.androidsoap.GenericHandler.parseWithPullParser(GenericHandler.java:243)
06-13 13:19:50.246: W/System.err(1317):     at org.jinouts.ws.WSInvocationHandler.invoke(WSInvocationHandler.java:99)
06-13 13:19:50.253: W/System.err(1317):     at $Proxy0.validateUserAndReturnDashBoard(Native Method)
06-13 13:19:50.253: W/System.err(1317):     at com.example.myfirstapp.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:64)
06-13 13:19:50.266: W/System.err(1317):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
06-13 13:19:50.273: W/System.err(1317):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
06-13 13:19:50.273: W/System.err(1317):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-13 13:19:50.273: W/System.err(1317):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-13 13:19:50.289: W/System.err(1317):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-13 13:19:50.294: W/System.err(1317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-13 13:19:50.294: W/System.err(1317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 13:19:50.294: W/System.err(1317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-13 13:19:50.313: W/System.err(1317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-13 13:19:50.313: W/System.err(1317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-13 13:19:50.333: W/System.err(1317):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-13 13:19:50.333: I/System.out(1317): ReflectionHelper*java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: value
06-13 13:19:50.346: W/System.err(1317): org.jinouts.ws.exception.FieldNotMatchedException
06-13 13:19:50.353: W/System.err(1317):     at hu.javaforum.commons.ReflectionHelper.getFieldClass(ReflectionHelper.java:504)
06-13 13:19:50.353: W/System.err(1317):     at hu.javaforum.android.androidsoap.GenericHandler.startElement(GenericHandler.java:345)
06-13 13:19:50.366: W/System.err(1317):     at hu.javaforum.android.androidsoap.GenericHandler.parseWithPullParser(GenericHandler.java:243)
06-13 13:19:50.366: W/System.err(1317):     at org.jinouts.ws.WSInvocationHandler.invoke(WSInvocationHandler.java:99)
06-13 13:19:50.373: W/System.err(1317):     at $Proxy0.validateUserAndReturnDashBoard(Native Method)
06-13 13:19:50.373: W/System.err(1317):     at com.example.myfirstapp.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:64)
06-13 13:19:50.393: W/System.err(1317):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
06-13 13:19:50.393: W/System.err(1317):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
06-13 13:19:50.413: W/System.err(1317):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-13 13:19:50.413: W/System.err(1317):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-13 13:19:50.413: W/System.err(1317):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-13 13:19:50.413: W/System.err(1317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-13 13:19:50.433: W/System.err(1317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 13:19:50.446: W/System.err(1317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-13 13:19:50.446: W/System.err(1317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-13 13:19:50.466: W/System.err(1317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-13 13:19:50.466: W/System.err(1317):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-13 13:19:50.473: W/System.err(1317): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
06-13 13:19:50.493: W/System.err(1317):     at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:401)
06-13 13:19:50.493: W/System.err(1317):     at hu.javaforum.android.androidsoap.GenericHandler.endElement(GenericHandler.java:468)
06-13 13:19:50.513: W/System.err(1317):     at hu.javaforum.android.androidsoap.GenericHandler.parseWithPullParser(GenericHandler.java:266)
06-13 13:19:50.513: W/System.err(1317):     at org.jinouts.ws.WSInvocationHandler.invoke(WSInvocationHandler.java:99)
06-13 13:19:50.526: W/System.err(1317):     at $Proxy0.validateUserAndReturnDashBoard(Native Method)
06-13 13:19:50.526: W/System.err(1317):     at com.example.myfirstapp.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:64)
06-13 13:19:50.526: W/System.err(1317):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
06-13 13:19:50.546: W/System.err(1317):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
06-13 13:19:50.546: W/System.err(1317):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-13 13:19:50.546: W/System.err(1317):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-13 13:19:50.566: W/System.err(1317):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-13 13:19:50.573: W/System.err(1317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-13 13:19:50.573: W/System.err(1317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 13:19:50.573: W/System.err(1317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-13 13:19:50.573: W/System.err(1317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-13 13:19:50.573: W/System.err(1317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-13 13:19:50.586: W/System.err(1317):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


MY code which is calling webservice inside onClick method:


StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()  
                          .detectDiskReads()  
                          .detectDiskWrites()  
                          .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems  
                          .penaltyLog()  
                          .build());  
                          StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()  
                          .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()  
                          .detectLeakedClosableObjects()  
                          .penaltyLog()  
                          .penaltyDeath()  
                          .build());  

                          Log.i("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","");      
                          LoginAppAPI a = new LoginAppAPI();
                          LoginAppAPIPortType port = a.getLoginAppAPISoap11Port();  
                          Log.i("PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP","");
                          Log.i("YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY", port.validateUserAndReturnDashBoard ());
```

This code is working fine in java client, only issue is with Android application

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import org.jinouts.xml.ws.BindingProvider;

import com.example.com.loginappapi.LoginAppAPI;
import com.example.com.loginappapi.LoginAppAPIPortType;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

//.import com.ws.*;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    EditText username, password;
    Button login;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setting default screen to login.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usrname);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passcode);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (username.getText().toString().equals("rox")
                        && password.getText().toString().equals("gw")) {
                    // responding to the User inputs
                    Log.i("ABC", "roshan");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Login Successfully !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Dashboard.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {

                    try {
                        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                        .permitAll().build();
                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                        LoginAppAPI api = new LoginAppAPI();
                        Log.i("XXXXXXXXXXXXX", api.toString());
                        LoginAppAPIPortType port = api
                                .getLoginAppAPISoap12Port();
                        // BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider)port;
                        // prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY,
                        // "su");
                        // prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,
                        // "gw");
                        // Log.i("ssssssssssssssssss", port.toString());
                        Log.i("YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
                                port.validateUserAndReturnDashBoard());
                        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                ListViewSample.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.i("errrrorrrrr", e.getMessage());

                    }
                }
            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: And what for answer do you exactly expect without showing any code?

Comment: I have attached my class and WSDL, can you please have  a look?